# What happens when I pass an CASE expression to the LAST_VALUE function

Tags: sql, window-functions

My LAST_VALUE function looks somethin like this

- ```
       LAST_VALUE(
           CASE 
               WHEN statement_1 then 0
               WHEN statement_2 then 1
               WHEN statement_3 then 0
               ELSE NULL
           END IGNORE NULLS)  OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2)
  ```

Can someone explains what value is the LAST_VALUE supposed to return if there is expression.
I understand what happens when a column is passed, but incase of such expressions no clue whatsoever.

Comment: Why don't you experiment and see? Copy the case expression as a new column and review the two columns side by side to see what the result is; does that even work with an alias within the last_value()?

Comment: A column is a simplest (but const) expression. Any expression is evaluated row by row in the oder specified in OVER.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the description and examples at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions085.htm#SQLRF00655
Regards...
Btw. the CASE ... END structure is just as you are selecting values from the table field but with If condition. It doesn't affect the LAST_VALUE function.
It is something like this:
CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN 10 WHEN ID = 2 THEN 20 ELSE 99 END
where ID = 1 is Statement1, ID = 2 is Statement2 ... and so on..

Comment: So even if the LAST_VALUE() is removed the Output will be the same, right?

Comment: Not the same - result of the LAST_VALUE is one of many that are processed. You have selected * (all columns) and beside that, in every row, one additional column that is returned by LAST_VALUE function. So if you remove LAST_VALUE the result will have one column less.

Answer (score 0):

The same as if your case expression were itself a column...

```
SELECT
  *,
  LAST_VALUE(new_column IGNORE NULLS)
    OVER (PARTITION BY column1
              ORDER BY column2
    )
FROM
(
   SELECT
     *,
     CASE 
         WHEN statement_1 then 0
         WHEN statement_2 then 1
         WHEN statement_3 then 0
         ELSE NULL
     END
       AS new_column
   FROM
     your_table
 )
   sub_query
```